# SSIS Import Sharepoint 2010 List to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, development, list

Is there a way to do this via code? How so? I simply want to import data from a list in SharePoint 2010 to a SQL 2005 or 2008 server.

I know there are several 3rd party plug-ins that work, but I can't run the jobs from the server automatically as I would have to buy the product.

I want come up with something that I don't have to buy.

Where would I start? Does anyone have code samples of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this without code by using BCS to connect to your SQL table with 2 way data update support, and use a workflow to transfer your sharepoint list to the external list (which would then write to your SQL table via BCS).

Comment: BCS = Business Connectivity Services, right? Also, how do you "connect to your SQL table with 2 way data update support, and use a workflow to transfer your sharepoint list to the external list"?

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652

Free codeplex Sharepoint List Adapters for SSIS 2008 and SSIS 2005.
I use these regularly in SSIS to download lists into SQL Server.